# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence in SVM for simple arrays

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

I am trying to use SVM on my dataset but I am getting the error `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`. My inputs are:

```
y = df['emotion'].values.tolist()
X = df['flatten_embeddings']
```

Where `y` us just target like `Sad, Angry, Neutral ...` and `X` is

```
0      [1.702582, 1.277809, 1.7816906, -5.0634155, 0....
1      [-1.1865704, -0.698246, -1.7263901, -3.2054596...
2      [-1.7968469, -0.18659484, 2.1262107, -5.183001...
3      [-1.9038239, -2.7165074, 0.022676349, -2.31133...
4      [-0.34684253, 0.58175063, -2.0320444, -0.65968...
Name: flatten_embeddings, Length: 400, dtype: object
```

When I use SVM, I get the error. The code is as follows:

```
from sklearn import svm
clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(X, y)
```

ERROR:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-0d786f0eb252> in <module>
      1 from sklearn import svm
      2 clf = svm.SVC()
----> 3 clf.fit(xxx, y)
```

I have tried to vectorize but get the same error.

```
yyy = X
xxx = np.array(list(map(np.double, yyy)))
```

Just for FYI, my rows are not same in size:

```
len(X[0]):  152576
len(X[1]):  101376
len(X[2]):  101376
```

Answer (score 0):

The hint at the end was really the issue. The error in actual was `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`. I used a function to pad all the rows with 0 with were less in size than row with max length.

```
# Find length of max row
max = max(map(len, X_arr))

# Pad the rows with 0
X_arr_same = np.array([np.pad(v, (0, m - len(v)), 'constant') for v in X_arr])
```

Result was:

```
len(X_arr_same[0]):  152576
len(X_arr_same[1]):  152576
len(X_arr_same[2]):  152576
```

This solved the issue and the block ran successfully,

```
from sklearn import svm
clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(X_arr_same, y)
```